# Is there an Inflector script for German language?

Tags: java, inflector

I am using [Java Inflector library](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/browse/net/java/dev/inflector/inflector/0.7.0/) to get English words plurals. It is working fine, but i wanted to ask:

**Is there a similar library for German language ?**

I have seen the [JInflector project](http://code.google.com/p/jinflector/) but it seems it has no progress.

Answer (score 2):

It's not software but here's a big XML file with inflected forms of German words under a free license: http://www.danielnaber.de/morphologie/ (Disclaimer: this is a link to my personal homepage). You could use that to create an inflector. For background information about how to create such a large word list without manually adding all forms, see the papers on [Morphy](http://www.wolfganglezius.de/doku.php?id=cl%3amorphy).

Answer (score 0):

Inflection works is much more difficult in German than in English.
So I think the only way is a huge look-up-table.

Couldn't you work with something like
Stuhl -> Stuhl (Pl.) what means Plural?